# How to join distinct values from the same column in one row with Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

| Name | Model | Age | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | short | 12 | 4.5 |
| Bob | big | 32 | 4 |
| Dav | big | 46 | 5 |

And i'd like to produce this:

| Name | Model | Age | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | ["short","big"] | 12 | 4.5 |
| Dav | big | 46 | 5 |

the remaining fields are filled with the data of the line that has the highest rating, and there should be no duplicate models.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to know exactly what logic will fit your use case without additional information about the data.

For example:

- Does it matter which age and rating is assigned to the name after aggregating the values for model?
- Will there ever be multiple rows with the same name and model? If so, do you want the model array to have the unique set of model names or include the duplicates?

Hopefully the below code will at least get you started down the right path.

I assumed that the value for age and rating can be any of the input rows with the given name. It also only produces the unique set of model names.

```scala
df.groupBy(col("name"))
  .agg(
    collect_set(col("model")).as("model"), // Unique set of model names in an array
    first(col("age")).as("age"),
    first(col("rating")).as("rating")
  )
```

Some other [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html) to look into might be: `collect_list`, `last`, `min`, `max`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, i edited the question according to the missing information